# Detect pipeline errors on whole project

Tags: intershop

I am trying to detect pipeline errors on a Intershop 7.10 project before the project is run or deployed.
This is the kind of errors I am talking about:
[image: Pipeline error]

Now what I am looking for is either setting for gradle build to fail when trying to build cartridge with such pipelines or either a view in Intershop studio that can show me this kind of errors on whole project (so far I couldn't find anything).

Currently the project is built with these kind of errors and they are only detected in logs when testing which can make them very hard to detect and fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Intershop Studio:**
You should be able to find a menu entry named `"Validate Cartridge Element"`
in the context menu of a given cartridge. That is performing a validation per code artifact found within that cartridge. Problems view shows you the results of that run.

**At build time:**
No this is not possible to activate.